# How to compare and SQL date in VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL Server database and what I want to do is compare a start date (`date`) and an end date (`date`) that I stored in my database on a row like this:

- Column1 - Row1 (start date) = 16-03-2016
- Column2 - Row1 (end date) = 16-03-2017

Both of these dates must be checked with the current date inside a sub in vb.net and I did this:

```
If RecieverData.HasRows Then
    While RecieverData.Read
        Label1Recieverinfo.Text = "Klant: " & RecieverData("Ontvanger").ToString
        Label2Recieverinfo.Text = "ID: " & RecieverData("OntvangerID").ToString
        Label3Recieverinfo.Text = "Event: " & RecieverData("event").ToString
        Label4Recieverinfo.Text = "Startdatum: " & RecieverData("Startdate").ToString
        Label5Recieverinfo.Text = "Einddatum: " & RecieverData("Enddate").ToString
    End While

    Dim StartDate As New Date
    Dim EndDate As New Date

    StartDate = RecieverData("StartDate")
    EndDate = RecieverData("EndDate")

    If StartDate <= Date.Now Then
        MessageBox.Show("startdate ok")
    ElseIf EndDate >= Date.Now Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enddate ok")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Use me")
    End If

Else
    MessageBox.Show("Deze Ontvanger ID bestaat niet.", "Fout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End If
```

But (you already knew this)  it doesn't work.

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks

Edit:

Label results:

[image]

Error that I get:

[image]

Comment: What doesnt work?  Do the dates appear ok in the labels?  Are they Date columns in the DB?  That `While` loop seems like an infinite loop

Comment: the while does run one time because i have one record that i select :)
I've put a screenshot of the results in the labels above.
they are date columns yes

Comment: You still need to define "it doesn't work".  Does the "startdate ok" MsgBox show?  BTW those conditions arent mutually exclusive - the StartDate can be < Now **and** the  EndDate >= Date.Now - the ElseIf wont show the end date msg with the data shown which fails the part about `both of these dates must be checked`

Comment: Your while loop is probably exiting after you have read past the end of the data.  What does "it doesn't work" mean?  Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Plutonix i took a screen, it's in the question

Comment: Your loop reads all the data: `While RecieverData.Read` then *outside* the loop when you have consumed it all, you are trying to read **more**: `StartDate = RecieverData("StartDate")`

Comment: that makes sense. omg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop is reading past the end of the data.  If you only expect one row, you should just read once:

```vb
If RecieverData.HasRows Then

    ' Read the first row
    RecieverData.Read()

    Label1Recieverinfo.Text = "Klant: " & RecieverData("Ontvanger").ToString
    Label2Recieverinfo.Text = "ID: " & RecieverData("OntvangerID").ToString
    Label3Recieverinfo.Text = "Event: " & RecieverData("event").ToString
    Label4Recieverinfo.Text = "Startdatum: " & RecieverData("Startdate").ToString
    Label5Recieverinfo.Text = "Einddatum: " & RecieverData("Enddate").ToString

    Dim StartDate As New Date
    Dim EndDate As New Date

    StartDate = RecieverData("StartDate")
    EndDate = RecieverData("EndDate")

    If StartDate <= Date.Now Then
        MessageBox.Show("startdate ok")
    ElseIf EndDate >= Date.Now Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enddate ok")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Use me")
    End If

Else
    MessageBox.Show("Deze Ontvanger ID bestaat niet.", "Fout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End If
```

Comment: The dates could also be read just once into DateTime vars and update the labels from them. @ThomasDutoit

Comment: @ThomasDutoit You probably also want to switch [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and fix the issues that raises.  Using the `ReceiverData.GetXXX` (e.g. `GetDateTime`) methods to pull out the data with the correct type may help with that.